# Eclipse: start a PHP script in a builder?

Tags: php, eclipse, cordova, builder

I'm using a combination of PHP and Phonegap. I use PHP to build the HTML-files that are used in the Phonegap-application.

So before I can run the application a PHP-build-script should be started. I now do this manually in a browser each time, but I'd prefer to setup a custom builder that does this for me, when I run the application.

Is this possible?  I've looked into Apache Ant and Phing, but if it's possible to just start a program (CLI or browser) that runs my PHP-script, I'd be very happy, but how?

Comment: How are you starting your application? Could you wrap it in a shell script that simply runs the builder using PHP-CLI then starts the app on success?

Comment: I run the application with Run AS - Android Application (from Eclipse), which I don't know how to start in a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `wget` (found a version for windows somewhere).
Usage :

wget.exe

-O -q "http://myproject/build.php"

Answer (score 0):

Phing would be the way to go. You could use the HttpGetTask to request the URLs from the localhost and save them out to HTML files. It should be easy to setup. If you want to make it purely CLI based, then create a simple PHP file that buffers the output from target PHP files.

Something like this.

```
ob_start();
include($file_path);
$str = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
file_put_contents($out_path,$str);
```

You won't have $_SERVER globals, but you shouldn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

In Project->Properties->Builders, create your builder, and in Location say

```
path_to/php
```

and in arguments, say

```
name-of-script.php
```

Just like you would for a bash script or whatever other builder you have.

Comment: This works, but you can not use the same URL as in a browser then. I solved this with using 'wget'.  With that you can have an URL as a parameter, it's basically the same as in a browser then.